# Intellij] Why Spring Boot resources folder not include war or war_exploded but in production folder?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I don't know why this is in a separate folder called production. Because of this, my application does not work after build, and I cannot even read application.properties files. This is the build.gradle file I set and the current folder structure.
I don't know why this production folder is here.

My gradle set

[image]

My folder structure

[image]

Comment: For starters stop trying to outsmart the defaults, second you are building a jar not a war, unless you apply the `war` plugin next to the `java` plugin. Also please don't post code as screenshots (or worse links to screenshots), those are unreadable and needs additional work to get a picture of your code. Use the approriate code tags.

Comment: `Because of this, my application does not work after build` The `production` directory is used for artifact and this is expected directory. This cannot cause any problems. What is the real issue you have? Please re-phrase the question and description accordingly for it to reflect you problem.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for my question. What I want to say is that I made a war_expanded folder and jar, but there is no resources folder in it. And also any static files and thymeleafs.

Comment: If you use Gradle - you must configure war artifact also using Gradle build files. Refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html